# Dialog on close: Keep the view changes

Tags: java, android

This is my dialog:

```java
@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public class Popup extends DialogFragment {
    private final int _layout;

    @SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
    public Popup(int layout) {
        _layout = layout;
    }

    @SuppressLint({"ClickableViewAccessibility", "ResourceType"})
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Nullable
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view =  inflater.inflate(_layout, container, false);

        return view;
    }
```

And this is how I invoke it:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, Popup.ICustomTts, Popup.ITarget, Popup.IDialog, Popup.IControl {
    private final Popup mPopupTurbine = new Popup(R.layout.fragment_turbine);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button turbineBtn = findViewById(R.id.turbine);
        turbineBtn.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            mPopupTurbine.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Speak");
        });
```

When I click outside of that dialog, it will be closed. The problem is, I do some changes in that dialog (e.g. typed a text in TextView) and then I close that dialog. When I want to show it again, all the changes are lost. So how can I just **hide** the dialog so that the changes are still there when I re-display it?

I think in MainActivity I could add `mPopupTurbine.getDialog().hide();` but where do I add this line of code?

Comment: Hi, Just as others have said, you can use ViewModel https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel 

Or if your data is not much, you can use SharedPreferences https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences. I use this to save small pieces of data like, locale, true-false settings etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `ViewModel` that lives throughout the life of your activity and remember your `Popup` fragment lives inside your activity.

Every time you make a change inside Popup save that data in a `LiveData` or `Flow`. Observe the `LiveData` inside Popup and update your UI.

Answer (score 1):

You can post back entered data to your MainActivity:

```
@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public class Popup extends DialogFragment {

    public Popup() {
        // fragment constructor must be empty        
    }

    private static final String LAYOUT_ID_KEY = "LAYOUT_ID_KEY";
    private static final String PARAM1_KEY = "PARAM1_KEY";

    public static Popup newInstance(int layoutId, String initialParam1) {
        Popup popup = new Popup();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt(LAYOUT_ID_KEY, layoutId);
        bundle.putString(PARAM1_KEY, initialParam1);
        popup.setArguments(bundle);
        return popup;
    }

    private PopupCallback popupCallback;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        popupCallback = (PopupCallback) context;
    }

    @Nullable
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        int layoutId = getArguments().getInt(LAYOUT_ID_KEY);
        final View view = inflater.inflate(layoutId, container, false);
        EditText editText = view.findViewById(R.id.edittext);
        // set latest value of param1        
        editText.setText(getArguments().getString(PARAM1_KEY));
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(@NonNull DialogInterface dialog) {
        EditText v = getView().findViewById(R.id.edittext);
        // post back the param1        
        popupCallback.onDismissPopup(v.getText().toString());
        super.onDismiss(dialog);
    }

    interface PopupCallback {
        void onDismissPopup(String param1);
    }
}
```

and receive and keep them in MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Popup.PopupCallback {

    private String param1Backup;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button turbineBtn = findViewById(R.id.turbine);
        turbineBtn.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Popup.newInstance(R.layout.fragment_turbine, param1Backup).show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Speak");
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDismissPopup(String param1) {
        param1Backup = param1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `viewModel` to save your current values and attach the lifecycle of `viewModel` with your activity to save the current state.
Purpose of `viewModel` is to survive the configuration changes in your app.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Singleton Class** to save those data temporarily and moment you invoke it check if you have saved any data in it and put it back in your dialog.

```
public class SingletonClass{

public boolean isDialogDone;
public string dialogTitle, dialogMsg;

        public static SingletonClass getInstance(){
            if (instance == null) {
                synchronized(SingletonClass.class) {
                    if (instance == null) {
                        instance = new SingletonClass();
                    }
                }
            }
            return instance;
        }
}
```

Then while invoking your dialogBox, you can simply check

```
if(!SingletonClass.getInstance().isDialogDone){
  editText.setText(SingletonClass.getInstance().dialogMsg);
}
```

Ofc you also need to add listener to your EditText so that you can save the msg user is typing.